# Why it is necessary to have $y\le 0$ in the given problem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Find the maximum and minimum values of $f(x,y)=xy$ subject to the constraint $x^2−y=12$. Assume that $y≤0$ for this problem. Why is this assumption needed?

**NOTE:** 
I just want to know the necessity of the last part .why it should be $y\le0$.please be elaborate and yes,graphical analysis will be appreciated . Thank you.

Comment: @Decaf-Math I don't see the relevance of this comment.

Comment: sorry?I didn't get your question.

Comment: There was no question. Someone had left a misleading comment but it is deleted now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what happens if this constraint is not asserted.

The problem then become  to optimize $x(x^2-12)$ which is an cubic equation which has no maximum nor minimum, making the question too simple for you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: But,why then the part is given?

Comment: so that it is more interesting to you?  rather than immediately saying that there is no maximum and minimum.

Comment: As was explained, if a constraint like $y \le 0$ were not given, then the problem would not make any sense since $f(x,y)$ would have no global extreme values.

Comment: If you reduce the problem to a question in $x$ again given the constraint, the question has a maximum and minimum. It make things more fun.

Comment: sorry...still i can't feel it.would you please please add a graph.

Comment: with or without the constraint, they are both valid questions. The thing is your teacher has decided to ask you one of those questions which of my opinion is more interesting. I have included the graph of $f(x) = x(x^2-12)$.

Comment: thanks for adding the graph...is the only reason is having that minima at $x=2$?

Comment: I am not sure that is the only reason, your question could have a physical phenomenon but I am not aware of. But imposing the constraint, we do have a minima there compared to the other case.

Comment: could you please tell me the role of that in this $3D$ graph https://www.geogebra.org/3d/pae3gpbe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85866/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-rakibul-islam-prince).